# which() command can find executable only with ./

Tags: python, linux, bash, pymatgen

I'm using pymatgen, which has a class BaderAnalysis (https://github.com/materialsproject/pymatgen/blob/v2020.4.29/pymatgen/command_line/bader_caller.py).
This class needs a executable called bader (binary from another source), so it checks if the file is there or not using which().
I do have the file and i can run the bader program manually, but I always get the error that the file isn't there. 
If I try the which() command manually it turns out that it only finds it with the prefix ./

```
print(which('bader'))
print(which('./bader'))
```

Output:
None

./bader

How can I make it in a way that the which command finds it without the prefix? (because the pymatgen class literally runs `if not which("bader") or which("bader.exe"): 'error message...'` when initializing the class.

Comment: which only searches based on the env PATH.  Try running the command from a shell in another directory.  You'll see that the exe is not found.  The ./ adds the current working directory to the path temporarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add your current directory to your `PATH` environment variable.  You can do it in your program invocation.  E.g.,

```
PATH=$PATH:$PWD python my_script.py
```